# How to get dxl scripts to run faster

Tags: ibm-doors

I have created a DXL script that goes through every row of a couple modules. I am printing out certain rows and its information. I am doing this by having a for loop that goes through the rows and if it hits a row that I am interested in, I save the elements in the columns of this row to different string variables and print those string variables. The script does not take too long to run if the module does not have a lot of rows I am interested in but if I want to run multiple modules at the same time or if a module has a lot of rows I am interested in, the script can take hours. I can show the code that I have if this is not enough to come up with solutions. Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried using a skip list to store the print statements in that and then tried going through the skip list to print each value but that did not make the script run any faster.

```
string sep=","
for o in m do
{
    string ver1= o."column1"


            if (checkIf(o) && (!(isDeleted(o))))
            {
                string ver2= o."column2"
                    string onum=number(o)
                     ""

                    string otext = o."Object Text"
                    print ver1 sep ver2 sep onum
              }
```

}

Comment: If you could share the code, there's lots of wiggle room in DXL to do time optimization.

Comment: I believe my error is because I also go through the links of an item(didn't mention or put that in example code... sorry about that) and forget to close them. What's the correct way to close a link if I go through them with by doing a for lr in o <-"*" do{...}

Comment: What is the 'checkIf' function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial optimization:

```
for o in m do
{
    if (checkIf(o) && (!(isDeleted(o)))) {
        //This doesn't appear to be used?
        //string otext = o."Object Text"
        print o."column1" "," o."column2" "," number(o) "\n"
    }
}
```

Reasoning: DOORS has a system in place called the string table that holds declared strings in memory- and doesn't necessarily do the best at clearing it out when appropriate. By constantly declaring strings in your loop, you might be bumping into the memory limits of that system.

Problem with this is that the results all end up in that 'DXL editor' little window, and then have to be copy and pasted somewhere else to actually use it.

Secondary optimization:

```
// Turn off runlimit for timing
pragma runLim , 0

// Set file location - CHANGE FOR YOUR COMPUTER
string csv_location = "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/Info_Collection.csv"

// Open stream
Stream out = append csv_location

// Set headers
out << "Module,Column 1,Column 2,Object Number" "\n"

// Define your loop constraints
Module m = current
Object o

// Run your loop
for o in m do
{
    if (checkIf(o) && (!(isDeleted(o)))) {
        //This doesn't appear to be used?
        //string otext = o."Object Text"
        out << fullName(m)","o."column1" "," o."column2" "," number(o) "\n"
    }
}

close out
```

This will let you run the same script in different modules, all outputting to the same CSV file, which you can then load into Excel or your data manipulation engine of choice.

This keeps the data collection happening outside of DOORS, so if something goes awry, you can track down where it occurred.

My third optimization would be to use a list of modules in, say, excel as an input and do this analysis, but that might be going too far.

If this doesn't help, then we can start examining other issues.

Note- I still would like to know what 'checkIf' is/does.

Comment: When I write to txt file, it appends to the end of the txt file. How would I overwrite what's already in the file?

Comment: Found the answer. Have to replace 'append' with 'write'.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to speed up the execution of the script, since most of the objects are of no interest to you, the most effective way I know of is to filter out most of the objects that are not interesting, e.g., a filter which is obj."Object Text" != "" would filter out Headings, if you are just interested in requirements, obj."Object Text" contains "[Ss]hall" etc. Save as a view for later use.
for o in m do { respects the display set, so if you don't touch most of the objects it will speed it up a lot!
Hope this helps.
Don